# How is 50-cloud-init.cfg created?

Tags: networking, cloud-init

As far as I can tell, it is created by code in the `cloudinit` package, which lives in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/distros/debian.py`. But where is *that* code called from?

What I need to do is generate additional files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`that know the network interface names. I don't want to just put them there, since this is an image that runs on AWS and different machine types have different interface names.